# how to scrape data from multiple pages in the same row

Tags: json, web-scraping

How to scrape data from multiple pages in the same row?

```
main page > next page (scrape title) > sub page (scrape img)
```

in my example:

```
all product > product page n°1 (scrape title) > sub page product n°1(scrape img)

            > product page n°2 (scrape title) > sub page product n°2 (scrape img)
```

result on my json  (bad):

- line 1 title_1 = ........ (product n°1)
- line 2 img_hd_1 = ........ (product n°1)
- line 3 title_1 = ........ (product n°2)
- line 4 img_hd_1 = ........ (product n°2)

desired result :

- line 1 title_1 = ........ , img_hd_1 = ........ (product n°1)
- line 2 title_1 = ........ , img_hd_1 = ........ (product n°2)

the results are good but not the structure.
how to scrape data from multiple pages in the same row?

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'quotesbij'
allowed_domains = ['test.com']
start_urls = ['http://test.com']

#page 1 : all url product
def parse(self, response):
    urls = response.css('div.item > div.info > h3 > a::attr(href)').extract()
    for url in urls:
        url = response.urljoin(url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_details_product)

#page 2 : scrape title from all url product
def parse_details_product(self, response):
    yield{
    'title': response.css('div.detail-wrap >h1::text').extract(),
    }

#page 2 : scrape url photo (same page of title)
    url_img = response.css('div.ui-image-viewer-thumb-wrap > a::attr(href)')[0].extract()
    for url in url_img:
        url_img = response.urljoin(url_img)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url_img, callback=self.parse_reviews)

#page 3 : scrape photo
def parse_reviews(self, response):
    yield{
    'img_hd_1': response.css('a > img::attr(src)').extract(),
    }
#The result is good but not the structure, how to scrape data from multiple pages in the same row?
```

Thank you.

Comment: In your loop `for url in photo_url:`, you are not using `url` anywhere and overwriting `photo_url` why?

Comment: I am asking you, in your code why you are not using `url` inside the loop?

Comment: In `parse_level_2`, `for url in photo_url:
        photo_url = response.urljoin(photo_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=photo_url, callback=self.parse_level_3)`

Comment: When you write a loop your intentions is to use the variable which takes each value, so `url` in this case and not `photo_url` which is the actual collection you are looping from? Like you have done in `parse_level_1`

Comment: I reformulated all my request.
Can you help me?

Comment: I will look into this tomorrow morning

Comment: You need to use `response.meta` to pass the item from one call to another. See this https://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.10.3/topics/request-response.html